# Create large number of array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, matrix

We know that in scala, to create a 2D array (matrix), ofDim is used:

```
def ofDim[T]( n1: Int, n2: Int ): Array[Array[T]]
```

where the parameters only accept Int  type.

What if I would like to create a 2D array with large quantity of elements, where long shall be used? Instead of ofDim, what else can I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Even if you have enough memory to have more than 2^31-1 elements of your data type, the JVM limits arrays to at most 2^31-1 in length.

So the short answer is: you can't.  And you probably don't have enough memory anyway.

But if you do, you can create your own class that wraps an array of arrays as a single array:

```
class BigArray[@specialized T: reflect.ClassTag](size: Long) {
  private val data = Array.ofDim(1 + (size >> 20).toInt, math.min(size, 1L << 20).toInt)
  def apply(i: Long): T = data((i >> 20).toInt)((i & ((1 << 20)-1)).toInt)
  def update(i: Long, value: T) {
    data((i >> 20).toInt)((i & ((1 << 20)-1)).toInt) = value
  }
}
```

and then use this.  Note that trying to put that much data in most any existing collection type will break it, so you will probably just have to index over it the old-style (manual) way.

Now that you have this, you can create BigArrays of BigArrays and manually index into them to place elements (and initialize the empty BigArrays).

But there's probably a better way to solve the problem that is making you want to create such huge arrays.